# v8 | manually initiate the garbage collector

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, v8

Is there a way to manually initiate the garbage collector on Google's V8 engine? I couldn't find any reference for it. by usually GCs support this function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- You can expose the `v8::HEAP->CollectAllGarbage` function to the
  global JavaScript namespace via the command flag `--expose_gc`. Then
  simply call `gc();`.
- You can force garbage collection from C++ via the statement:

  `while(!V8::IdleNotification()) {};`

References:

- http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/extensions/gc-extension.cc
- http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1688

Comment: V8::IdleNotification doesn't seem to exist anymore http://v8.paulfryzel.com/docs/master/classv8_1_1_v8.html

Answer (score 1):

Use V8::AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemory

http://create.tpsitulsa.com/wiki/V8/Garbage_Collection

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for, but close enough. thanks.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel Better answer your own question when you found a better answer and not accept a wrong answer.

Comment: Link is dead and that function or field doesn't seem to exist anymore http://v8.paulfryzel.com/docs/master/classv8_1_1_v8.html  It's in Isolate now: http://v8.paulfryzel.com/docs/master/classv8_1_1_isolate.html

Comment: Everything that used to be global in the v8 namespace has been moved to isolate, as each isolate is independent.   isolate->AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemory  is the new function and you use it to adjust how much memory v8 thinks is being used to back the objects it knows about.   When you create a c++ object for v8 to know about, you usually want to pass in sizeof(CppObjectType) and when you delete the c++ object, pass in -sizeof(CppObjectType).   For testing, you can simply tell v8 that each object uses a lot of memory and it will garbage collect more aggressively