# Javascript and Garbage collection

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Is there any way to control when Javascript performs garbage collection? I would like to enable it to perform garbage collection at certain times to ensure the smooth operation of my web site

Comment: In a word: no. This isn't a problem for many sites. Maybe you could explian in more detail what the problem is with yours?

Comment: [Writing Fast, Memory-Efficient JavaScript](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/), [Memory Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)

Comment: [High-Performance, Garbage-Collector-Friendly Code](http://buildnewgames.com/garbage-collector-friendly-code/)

Comment: Why the downvote? Got a good couple of references to read.

Comment: When using node, you can run node app with v8 option `--expose_gc` then you can simply call function `gc()`. I found this answer from question [v8 | manually initiate the garbage collector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719967/v8-manually-initiate-the-garbage-collector)

Comment: If the code is executed browser-side then no that is the responsibilty of browser. If you were executing it server-side like with node or rhino then yes. Do note that using gc requires care as it can hangup execution.

Comment: Some support which can give a couple of ideas how to actually reduce the GC activity in Javascript, can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18364175/270315

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have explicit memory management, it's the browser which decides when to clean it up. Sometimes it may happen that you experience un-smooth rendering of JavaScript due to a garbage collection pause.

There are many techniques that you can apply to overcome glitches caused by garbage collection (GC). More you apply more you explore. Suppose you have a game written in JavaScript , and every second you are creating a new object then its obvious that at after certain amount of time GC will occur to make further space for your application.

For real time application like games, which requires lot of space the simplest thing you can do is to reuse the same memory. It depends on you how you structure your code. If it generates lots of garbage then it might give choppy experience.

**By using simple procedures:** This is well know that new keyword indicates allocation. Wherever possible you can try to reuse the same object by each time by adding or modifying properties. This is also called **recycling of object**

**In case of Arrays**, assigning [] is often used to clear array, but you should keep in mind that it also creates a new array and garbages the old one. To reuse the same block you should use `arr.length = 0` This has the same effect but it reuses the same array object instead of creating new one.

**In case of functions**: Sometimes our program needed to call a specific function more time or on certain intervals by using setInterval or setTimeout.

```
ex: setTimeout(function() { doSomething() }, 10);
```

You can optimize the above code by assigning the function to a permanent variable rather than spawning each time at regular intervals.

```
    ex : var myfunc = function() { doSomething() }
    setTimeout(myfunc, 10);
```

Other possible thing is that, the array slice() method returns a new array (based on a range in the original array,that can remain untouched), string's substr also returns a new string (based on a range of characters in the original string, that can remain untouched), and so on. Calling these functions creates garbage if not reutilized properly.

To avoid garbage completely in JavaScript is very difficult, you could say impossible. Its depends, how you reuse the objects and variables to avoid garbage. If your code is well structured and optimized you can minimize the overhead.

Comment: If you are going to do all of that, might it be better to write the game in C++ and compile it to asm.js via Emscripten?  No GC to worry about :)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there is no way to control WHEN the garbage collection takes place but with the proper formation of objects, you CAN control how quickly and cleanly it happens. Take a look at [these documents on Mozilla Dev Net](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection).

> This algorithm assumes the knowledge of a set of objects called roots
>   (In JavaScript, the root is the global object). Periodically, the
>   garbage-collector will start from these roots, find all objects that
>   are referenced from these roots, then all objects referenced from
>   these, etc. Starting from the roots, the garbage collector will thus
>   find all reachable objects and collect all non-reachable objects.
>
> This algorithm is better than the previous one since "an object has
>   zero reference" leads to this object being unreachable. The opposite
>   is not true as we have seen with cycles.

Comment: Is only global object a root ?
What about the variables on stack for functional execution context ?
They would also reference memory on heap
when function ends, the references on stack are removed but the mem remains on heap ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not keep references to all your objects until you want them to be GC'd?

```
var delayed_gc_objects = [];
function delayGC(obj) { // keeps reference alive
    return delayed_gc_objects[delayed_gc_objects.length] = obj;
}
function resumeGC() { // kills references, letting them be GCd
    delayed_gc_objects.length = 0;
}
```

Comment: That only delays reclamation (sweeping), not reachability checking (tracing) let alone garbage collection as a whole. In other words, it only makes the GC waste time.

Answer (score 0):

you can perform some changes to improve your memory use, like:

1. don't set variables on loops
2. avoid using of global variables and functions. they will take a piece of memory until you get out

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a garbage-collected language, meaning that the execution environment is responsible for managing the memory required during code execution. 
The most popular form of garbage collection for JavaScript is called mark-and-sweep.
A second, less-popular type of garbage collection is reference counting. The idea is that every value keeps track of how many references are made to it

GC follows these algo, even if you manage to trigger the GC, it will not be guaranteed that it will run immediately, you are only marking it

Comment: Since there is no finalize, isn't those that are unmarked removed?

Answer (score -3):

garbage collection (GC) is a form of automatic memory management by removing the objects that no needed anymore.

any process deal with memory follow these steps:

1 - allocate your memory space you need

2 - do some processing

3 - free this memory space

there are two main algorithm used to detect which objects no needed anymore.

Reference-counting garbage collection: this algorithm reduces the definition of "an object is not needed anymore" to "an object has no other object referencing to it", the object will removed if no reference point to it

Mark-and-sweep algorithm: connect each objects to root source. any object doesn't connect to root or other object. this object will be removed.

currently most modern browsers using the second algorithm.

Comment: I know what garbage collection is. The question is how to control when this happens.