# JavaScript garbage collection with closures

Tags: javascript

When can `o` be garbage collected? I presume after the completion of the `setTimeout` callback?

```
var o = {
    foo() {
        setTimeout(function() {}, 10000);
    }
};

o.foo();
o = null;
```

And this one?

```
var o = {
    bar: 0
};

o.foo = function() {
    setTimeout(function() { o.bar; }, 10000);
}

o.foo(); // Sorry missed this important bit.
o = null;
```

Comment: May help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800440/javascript-and-garbage-collection

Comment: @TJ Crowder, ok thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Side note: For anyone wondering whether Ben's code is syntactically correct: Yes, it is, as of ES2015; it wouldn't be in ES5 or earlier. It's using the new "[method definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-method-definitions)" syntax ES2015 defines for object initializers.)*

Re your first question, on this code:

```
var o = {
    foo() {
        setTimeout(function() {}, 10000);
    }
};

o.foo();
o = null;
```

The object initially assigned to `o` is eligible for GC right away, even before the timer callback, because nothing keeps a reference to it after the `o = null;` statement.

But there are other objects that may or may not be eligible for GC, it depends on theory (the specification) vs. practice (implementation optimizations not ruled out by the spec):

Until the timer callback occurs, the timer mechanism keeps a reference to the anonymous function, and so that anonymous function isn't eligible for GC.

In theory, the anonymous function has a reference to the environment object in which it was created, which in turn has a reference to `foo`, and so the anonymous function keeps both the environment and `foo` in memory until the timer fires, releases its reference, and the anonymous function is eligible for GC.

In practice, since the anonymous function doesn't reference `foo` or any arguments or local variables within `foo` (and doesn't use `eval`), a JavaScript implementation is free to optimize and allow `foo` and that environment object to be GC'd even though the `setTimeout` call still has a reference to that anonymous function. (And some do indeed do closure optimization, such as V8.) They can do that because we can't see any side-effects from it other than memory consumption or the lack thereof.

---

Re your additional question, on this code:

```
var o = {
    bar: 0,
    foo() {
        setTimeout(function() { o.bar; }, 10000);
  }
};

o.foo();
o = null;
```

The object itself is still eligible for GC immediately.

Re `foo` and the environment object for the call to it:

In theory, they're both retained (as they were above). In practice, I don't know if that affects the optimization that the engine can do around `foo` and the environment for the call or not. It shouldn't, because the `o` variable is bound to the global environment, not the one set up by the call to `foo`, and so the environment chain could be edited to skip the environment created by the call to `foo`. So engines *could* optimize it, and at a total guess I'd say they probably do, but I don't know that they do.

Comment: Does `setTimeout()` call guarantee that the closure will still be there? I thought timeout closure could also be garbage collected at once, even before timeout triggers, if nothing references it.

Comment: @NoxNoctis do you refer to the "anonymous function" when you say "closure"? "if nothing references it" --- it is referenced by a timer queue.

Comment: @T.J Crowder Sorry, I made a mistake in my original posting. Corrected now.

Comment: @NoxNoctis: The timer mechanism has a reference to the anonymous function, thus preventing it from being GC'd until it releases that reference (after it fires and calls the function). As I said above, the anonymous function has an (indirect) reference to `foo`, in theory keeping `foo` in memory until the anonymous function is also eligible for GC, but in practice modern engines can optimize that reference to `foo` away.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see. Is timer referencing mechanism a part of the JS standard? I'm just curious, because in actionscript1 (which is ecma 262 and all, and is copy-and-paste compatible with JS) Flash Player's avm1 GC can remove anonymous functions from the memory if they are not referenced and thus halt `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()`. This was a typical pitfall for beginners.

Comment: @RobG: That's what I said, e.g., theory (specification) vs. reality (implementation optimization). I've edited to define what I mean by theory vs. reality.

Comment: @NoxNoctis: The specification addresses function references. The timer mechanism obviously has a reference to the function it's waiting to call. I don't know anything about ActionScript, but whether a function is anonymous or not has no bearing whatsoever on whether or when it's eligible for GC in JavaScript, other than that a function *declaration* (not expression) will create a binding to the function in the environment where the declaration occurs, thus retaining the function for as long as that environment exists.

Answer (score 0):

It differs from browser to browser, but rule of thumb is that an object is garbage collected once all of its references are either missing or null or both.

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection

Comment: "all of its references are either missing **or null**" --- the bolded part is wrong. A reference cannot be `null`, by definition.